# All the group formatting available in Mathematica

Tags: notebooks, formatting, style, stylesheet, keyboard

I was wondering how many pre-defined group formatting style there is in Mathematica. From `Format -> Style`, one see that we can go from `Title` (for Alt+1) to `Subsubsection` (Alt+6). However, this does not seem to be exhaustive. This is because, if I press Tab on a line created from any of those formattings (from Alt+1 to Alt+6), then I can automatically "move down one level" each time. However, from `Subsubsection`, it seems that I can still go 2 more levels down, after which Tab does its "normal" job.
Are these 2 additional formattings somewhere to be found in some documentation? Are they in any way "special" and can I assign keyboard shortcuts for them as for the other ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option `StyleKeyMapping` controls `"Tab"` and `"Backspace"` does to the style (AFAIK, it is not documented).

```
Row[Table[Most@NestWhileList["Tab" /. CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, #, StyleKeyMapping}]&,
     i, Not[StringMatchQ[#, "Tab"]] &] // Column[Style[#, #] & /@ #] &,
 {i, {"Chapter", "Title", "Section", "Item", "ItemParagraph", "ItemNumbered"}}], Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

The styles `"Subsubsubsection"` and `"Subsubsubsubsection"` are not listed in the `Format >> Style` menu.

The `StyleKeyMapping` option value for some `"*section"` styles are:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Subsection", StyleKeyMapping}]
```

> {"Tab" -> "Subsubsection", "Backspace" -> "Section", 
>        KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers -> {Shift}] -> "Section"}

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Subsubsection", StyleKeyMapping}]
```

> {"Tab" -> "Subsubsubsection", "Backspace" -> "Subsection", 
>    KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers -> {Shift}] -> "Subsection"}

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Subsubsubsection", StyleKeyMapping}]
```

> {"Tab" -> "Subsubsubsubsection", "Backspace" -> "Subsubsection", 
>    KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers -> {Shift}] -> "Subsubsection"}

To see the full style definitions, you can use

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Subsubsubsection"}]
```

> {CellMargins -> {{66, Inherited}, {2, 10}},
>    StyleKeyMapping -> {"Tab" -> "Subsubsubsubsection", 
>      "Backspace" -> "Subsubsection", 
>      KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers -> {Shift}] -> "Subsubsection"},
>    CellGroupingRules -> {"SectionGrouping", 60},
>    PageBreakBelow -> False, LanguageCategory -> "NaturalLanguage", 
>    CounterIncrements -> "Subsubsubsection",
>    CounterAssignments -> {{"Subsubsubsubsection", 0}, {"Item", 
>       0}, {"Subitem", 0}, {"Subsubitem", 0}, {"ItemNumbered", 
>       0}, {"SubitemNumbered", 0}, {"SubsubitemNumbered", 0}}, 
>    MenuSortingValue -> None, FontFamily -> "Source Sans Pro",
>    FontSize -> 15, FontWeight -> "Bold",
>    FontColor -> RGBColor[0.778286411841001, 0.4230563820859083, 0.16115053025101092`]}

Similarly for `'Subsubsubsubsection"`.

Comment: Huh I'd never seen `KeyEvent` in a `StyleKeyMapping`. That's super useful. I can get away with fewer magic keys.

Comment: Very nice. Would there be a way to assign keyboard shortcuts for them though?

Comment: @Patrick.B, you can try  [MenuCommandKey](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MenuCommandKey.html)